# Can we determine the information loss in regression function (if we reduce its dimensionality) by only comparing the corresponding outputs?

Tags: information-theory

I have a non-linear regression function that outputs $f_1(2)=7\pm 0.1$ and say if I reduce the dimensionality of the parameters of the function and create second function that outputs $f_2(2)=6.7 \pm 0.8$ at the same input $2$.

Question: Is it possible to determine the relative information loss by only looking at the outputs of the two functions?

Comment: why your two functions are the same?

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER sorry, fixed now.